# Try to pass an array of int in a custom function, doens't get the content of the array in the custom function

Tags: c

I try to create an array of int in C, and then, use it in a custom function :

```
int a[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
int* new_a = extract(a, 2, 4); 

// ...

int *extract(int* T, int a, int b){
    int lenght_T = getLenghtOfSimpleArray(T);
...
}
```

I use the IDE visual code, when I inspect the code through the degugger, I get :

[image]

I don't understand why, in the debugger, the value of T is not {1,3,5,7,9}...
Where is my mystake ?

Comment: The parameter `int* T` makes `T` a pointer to `int`. There is no way to know that it is actually an array.

Comment: I don't see how `getLenghtOfSimpleArray` possibly has enough information to return the length of the array.

Comment: @ikegami that's probably the OP's next question.

Comment: Instead of `extract(int *T, ...` you could write `extract(int T[100], ...`, then the debugger should know that `T` is actually an array of 100 `int`s rather than simply a pointer to `int` and display it accordingly. Sadly the Visual Studio debugger doesn't care, at least the version I'm using.

Comment: @matthieu lopez There are no exceptions in C.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I know ;) and this is why I create my own exception function haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass an array to a function it gets degraded to a pointer that points to the first element of the array. That means, `T` is an address in memory, so the big hex value shown in the debugger looks normal.

The debugger also shows `*T`, which is the value where the pointer points to, i.e. the first element of the array. The value is `1` as expected.

There is no way to find out the size/length of an array passed to a function this way, so it is not possible to make a working function `getLenghtOfSimpleArray`, except if you define an "invalid" value ([sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)) which must be put to the last element of the array. In the general case, the caller must pass the size of the array to the function in addition to the array name = pointer to the first element.

example code with passing the array length

```
int a[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
int* new_a = extract(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), 2, 4); 

int *extract(int* T, size_t length, int a, int b){
    int lenght_T = getLenghtOfSimpleArray(T);
...
}
```

Comment: The proper term is "[sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value)"

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not pointers. Pointers are not arrays.

`T` is not an array, it's a pointer to the first element. As you can see from your debugger, `*T` is `1`, which is that first element.

Most debuggers support watches such as `T[1]` etc if you wish to inspect individual items beyond the first. Or they have a "range" feature that allows you to view a number of items.

Comment: Notably, since arrays decay into pointers to the first element when passed as parameters, you might be able to provide more info for the debugger by declaring the parameter as `int T[5]` instead. Which in this case is equivalent to `int*` but with more type info provided.

Answer (score 0):

In C, arrays are just values in the memory right next to each other, and the pointer only points to the first entry.

So in your case if you want to access the other values you have to access them with `T[index]`

The debugger only shows the first value of the array in this case.